# Updating a value in a factory using ng-modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory that holds all of the information for the user that's signed into my application. For the sake of solving the issue, I've removed a lot of unecessary code.

```js
angular.module('app-user', []).factory('$user', function() {
    var biography = '';
    return {
        biography: biography
    }
});

angular.module('app', ['app-user']).controller('controller', function($scope, $user) {
  
  $scope.biography = $user.biography;
  
  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log("Scope: " + $scope.biography + "\nFactory: " + $user.biography);
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <input type="text" ng-modal="biography" placeholder="Click here to edit biography">
  <button ng-click="test()">Click here to log to console</button>
  <br>
  Biography: {{biography}}
</div>
```

As you can see, even though I've linked to the variable using `ng-modal` it is not being updated in either the `$scope` or `$user` service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is

```
$scope.biography = $user.biography;
```

assiging value of factories biography to scope's biography

This won't act as two way binding.

Only `Date,function,object,array` will hold reference.

Try like this

```
$scope.model= $user;
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.biography" placeholder="Click here to edit biography">
```

Comment: It's still won't work since he mistyped `ng-model` as `ng-modal`.

Comment: Only line that was needed: `Only Date,function,object,array will hold reference.` Thanks, Solved.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi - Had to wait the timelimit

Answer (score 3):

First, In your HTML, change `ng-modal` to `ng-model`. (that's why $scope.biography is not being updated).

also, when you assign a string variable into another it's copying the value, and not referencing.

You could try something like this:

```
angular.module('app-user', []).factory('$user', function() {
    var biography = {value: ''};
    return {
        biography: biography
    }
});

angular.module('app', ['app-user']).controller('controller', function($scope, $user) {

  $scope.biography = $user.biography;

  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log("Scope: ", $scope.biography,"\nFactory: ", $user.biography);
  };

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <input type="text" ng-model="biography.value" placeholder="Click here to edit biography">
  <button ng-click="test()">Click here to log to console</button>
  <br>
  Biography: {{biography.value}}
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9sam73e/